# How to add gallery support in WordPress?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I'm creating a custom post type and I have it support featured images but I don't know how to add support for galleries as well as WooCommerce does. The idea is to add another featured image panel which accept multiple images that I can show on the front end.

Thank you for you suggestions on how manage both adding support in back end and echo it in the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gallery-metabox. Its open source and easy to use;

https://github.com/zulfnore/gallery-metabox

From Readme ;

Include the `gallery.php` in your `functions.php`:

`require_once 'gallery-metabox/gallery.php';`

Specify where you want the gallery metabox to show on line 17 in `gallery.php`. You can pass an array to have it show up on multiple post types, custom post types are also allowed:

`$types = array('post', 'page', 'custom-post-type');`

In your template inside a loop, grab the IDs of all the images with the following:

`$images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vdw_gallery_id', true);`

Then you can loop through the IDs and call `wp_get_attachment_link` or `wp_get_attachment_image` to display the images with or without a link respectively:

`foreach ($images as $image) {
  echo wp_get_attachment_link($image, 'large');
  // echo wp_get_attachment_image($image, 'large');
}`